# How open my app with Deep linking on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using deep linking to open my app, on the iPhone it works perfectly when you put the URL in the browser (`myapp://my-view/params`), but when I do the same process on Android, it does a search on Google.

Answer (score 0):

How do you open the link

Try this

[From the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

```
import { Linking, Alert } from "react-native";
```

```
const url= "slack://open?team=123456";
const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

    if (supported) {
     // Opening the link with some app, if the URL scheme is "http" the web link should be opened
      // by some browser in the mobile
      await Linking.openURL(url);
    } else {
     Alert.alert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`);
}
```

Comment: no, my question is how to set up a link on my website to open my app on a given page, or send a link to email and open my app. on iOS I already test that using the URL on safari like this: `myapp://my-view/params` works, but on Android it doesn't, so I don't know how to generate a link to use in these cases and open my app